# Check in header file if lightswitch field is on

Tags: templating, entries, lightswitch

For a menu I have to check if a `lightswitch` field is on or not. The menu is in an extra header file. I've tried:

```
{% if craft.entries.section('aboutus').lightswitch_field %}style="display: none;"{% else %} ... {% endif %}
```

but this always jumps into the `else` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if craft.entries.section('aboutus').lightswitch_field('1')|length
```

If you want to check if it is "off" use:

```
if craft.entries.section('aboutus').lightswitch_field('not 1')|length
```

Comment: This sadly does not work. Both returns true. Any other idea?

Comment: Updated my answer.